# Cannot view authorization header

Tags: node.js, http, webserver

I'm using node.js default HTTP module and have an **HTTP webserver**.

I use request.headers to get all headers, but when I try to do request.headers.authorization it returns undefined, but there IS authorization [as you can see here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsQi7.png)

I tried to do JSON.parse(request.headers).authorization, still undefined, and crashes the process. How can I get the authorization header content?

Comment: Are you using any framework? Or native?

Comment: I'm using default HTTP module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use the method `request.getHeader(name)`
I looked in https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_getheader_name

Edit 1:

index.js

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  console.log(request.headers);
  console.log(request.headers.authorization);
  console.log('----');

  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  };
  let statusCode = 404;
  response.writeHead(200, headers);
  response.end('Hi');
});

server.listen(8080, () => {
 console.log(`Server listening on port :8080 `);
});
```

Executing in terminal one:

`node index.js`

Terminal two:

`curl localhost:8080 -H 'authorization: hello'`

The output in terminal one is:

```
{ host: 'localhost:8080',
  'user-agent': 'curl/7.68.0',
  accept: '*/*',
  authorization: 'hello' }
hello
----
```

Comment: Nope. I get TypeError: request.getHeader is not a function